# Rogue splash page keeps popping up

Tags: plugins, permalinks

So I have this website, and all seems to be running fairly smoothly except for this particular, pretty-likely scenario:

When you enter the website from the current splash page, you're taken to the About page. All copacetic. Navigating to other pages is also fine. However, once you click back to the about page, it directs you to a splash page from an old plugin I have since deleted. Furthermore, this splash page only routes back to itself. To top it all off? It shares the same permalink as the about page itself, so I can't find where or what to remove to rid this page.

My website is www.duncankrummel.com

Any help at all is appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

You have to permalinks for the about us page 1 is /About 2 is /about all you need to do is update your menu with the correct page link which is the /About page if that makes any sense